# main.xml: java.lang.NullPointerException Android Eclipse Error

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

So I just installed the Android SDK and the ADT addon for eclipse and ran into a problem.

When I go to the graphical layout in main.xml no layout shows up. Instead I just get this error

```
    $java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getInitELC(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.initFontConfig(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WFontConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment.createFontConfiguration(Unknown Source)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(Unknown Source)
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getDefaultFrc(Unknown Source)
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getFontMetrics(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.getFontMetrics(Unknown Source)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.updateFontObject(Paint_Delegate.java:1062)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.reset(Paint_Delegate.java:1039)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.<init>(Paint_Delegate.java:991)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.native_init(Paint_Delegate.java:614)
at android.graphics.Paint.native_init(Paint.java)
at android.graphics.Paint.<init>(Paint.java:194)
at android.graphics.Paint.<init>(Paint.java:184)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:278)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:116)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:227)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:318)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1317)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1071)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ConfigListener.onConfigurationChange(GraphicalEditorPart.java:493)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.onRenderingTargetChange(ConfigurationComposite.java:2192)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.access$4(ConfigurationComposite.java:2157)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite$2.widgetSelected(ConfigurationComposite.java:441)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

It doesnt matter what android version I am in I still get this error. I have tried uninstalling the SDK and the addon and to no avail. I am using SDK r14 tools and the ADT 14.0.

Anyone got any suggestions

Comment: include the source code please :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does it happen as soon as you open the XML file?

It may be worth checking the source in the XML file. Open the directory to where the file is contained and edit it (in Notepad etc) and just paste the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hi, did this work?" />
</LinearLayout>
```

That's about as simple as it gets. If that works, you know the XML in your current main.xml is wrong.

May also be worth rebuilding/cleaning your project.

Comment: No luck, no matter what device I select on the top right I still get the java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to view the graphical layout, its like it is missing this all together. Like I tried reinstalling it from scratch on both the SDK and ADT and same thing happens.